# 'OneToOneField' object has no attribute 'get' in function-based view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am writing a two-part form where I want to pass the object saved in the first part as a OneToOneField for the object in the second part.

In views.py:

```
def object_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title_form = TitleEntry(request.POST)
        object_form = ObjectEntry(request.POST)
        if title_form.is_valid():
            title = title_form.cleaned_data['title']
            title_type = title_form.cleaned_data['title_type']
            title_lang = title_form.cleaned_data['lang']
            title_translation = title_form.cleaned_data['translation']
            title_currency = title_form.cleaned_data['currency']
            title_level = title_form.cleaned_data['level']
            title_note = title_form.cleaned_data['note']
            title_source = title_form.cleaned_data['source']
            new_title = title_form.save()
            return new_title

        else:
            return render_to_response('objectinfo/objectregister_form.html', {'object_form': object_form, 'title_form': title_form})

        if object_form.is_valid():
            object_form.preferred_title = new_title
            snapshot = object_form.cleaned_data['snapshot']
            work_type = object_form.cleaned_data['work_type']
            source = object_form.cleaned_data['source']
            brief_description = object_form.cleaned_data['brief_description']
            description_source = object_form.cleaned_data['description_source']
            comments = object_form.cleaned_data['comments']
            distinguishing_features = object_form.cleaned_data['distinguishing_features']
            new_object = object_form.save()
            reorg.AccessionNumber.generate(new_object.pk)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/work/')
            # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(description_edit, args=(new_object.pk,)))

        else:
            return render_to_response('objectinfo/objectregister_form.html', {'object_form': object_form, 'title_form': title_form})

    else:
        title_form = TitleEntry()
        object_form = ObjectEntry()
        return render(request, 'objectinfo/objectregister_form.html', {'object_form': object_form, 'title_form': title_form})
```

And in forms.py:

```
class ObjectEntry(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ObjectRegister
        fields = ['snapshot', 'work_type', 'source', 'brief_description', 'description_source', 'comments', 'distinguishing_features', 'storage_unit', 'normal_unit']

 class TitleEntry(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ObjectName
        fields = ['title', 'title_type', 'lang', 'translation', 'currency', 'level', 'note', 'source']
```

When submitting the form it returns the error `'ObjectName' object has no attribute 'get'`. Traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/work/add/

Django Version: 1.10.6
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'reversion',
 'historicdate.apps.HistoricdateConfig',
 'place.apps.PlaceConfig',
 'agent.apps.AgentConfig',
 'storageunit.apps.StorageunitConfig',
 'objectinfo.apps.ObjectinfoConfig',
 'reorg.apps.ReorgConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback:

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py" in __call__
  138.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py" in process_response
  32.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /work/add/
Exception Value: 'ObjectName' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What would be the correct way to pass `new_title` as the OneToOneField of `object_form.preferred_title`?

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: All of those variable assignments inside the is_valid clauses appear to be pointless.

Comment: @Alasdair : thanks, see edited question

Comment: You're using a mixture of `render` and `render_to_response`. You should use `render` everywhere - `render_to_response` is obsolete.

Comment: Also, note that your view will never get to `if object_form.is_valid():`, because both branches of `if title_form.is_valid():` have return statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is returning the new instance if the form is valid. This is incorrect, you should always return an HTTP response.

```
    if title_form.is_valid():
        ...
        return new_title
```

It's a good idea to redirect after you have processed a valid form, to prevent duplicate form submissions.

Comment: Do you mean to say there cannot be two forms on the same template, i.e. I should first have a page with the title form and then, when that form has saved, display a separate page for the object form?

Comment: It is possible to have two forms on the same template. When you return a response, it would be better to redirect, to prevent duplicate submissions.

Comment: Thanks. I still can't figure out how to make the two forms work on the same template, so I split them into two separate views and passed the id of the first as a kwarg to the second.